# What does being three of the best refering to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is being three of the best referring to Himalayan Pink Salt? and two salts which are harvested in land refering to Celtic sea salt and Redmonds salt

> Those who follow my teachings on health and nutrition are aware of the importance I place upon the consumption of "superfoods" as part of our daily practices. They not only give us far greater types and amounts of nutrients, they also bring much higher prana (life force energy) into our bodies—the primary (i.e. higher) function of eating in the first place, since it is prana that sustains our life. Food, as I have said before, is merely one of the major vehicles which deliver prana into our bodies. It is for this reason that eating superfoods (as well as raw foods) helps us to reduce our overall food intake. Unrefined sea salt is one such superfood (Celtic, Redmonds, and Himalayan pink salt—all are sea salts, even though two are harvested on land—**being three of the best and richest in the world**). While salt is often labeled by nutritionists as unhealthy and even dangerous for the body, it is refined (a.k.a. table) salt which has earned this acclaimed title. Refined salt not only does not provide us with the many minerals we need, it actually leaches minerals from the body! In other words, it is more than unhealthy; it is toxic to the body. On the other hand, unrefined sea salt is a necessary food, the balanced consumption of which has many positive effects on the body. The following article by Dr. Brownstein does a very good job of presenting the facts about refined and unrefined salt. Enjoy…

Comment: I don't think this was written well, as the bold phrase seems to be in the wrong position. What is the source? You should always add a link to it or add a citation.

Answer (score 2):

The participle phrase **being three of the best and richest in the world** describes **Celtic, Redmonds, and Himalayan pink salt** earlier in the sentence.

Compare:

> Professional sports teams often pay their players exorbitant amounts of money (**Chelsea, Arsenal, and Manchester City**—all are British Premier League teams, although staffed with players from many different countries—**being three** of the wealthiest in the world).

Comment: Thank u for answering first part of the question. Secondly _Although two are harvested on land_ , here author referring to which two salts?

Comment: The author does not indicate which two salts are the ones harvested on land. I would assume that Himalayan is one of them :)